# How to use phone keyboard on google glass

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, google-glass

Question is simple , is it possible to use my phone`s keyboard on google glass to type letters ? İ couldnt find any accurate solution does anybody know anything? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can use apps like `TabletRemote/DroidMote`: install that on both devices and try to control your glass as any other android (I'm not sure, if this app would work for you, just try).

Another option is to use `Bluetooth keyboard/mouse`.
From what I have seen here: [Voiding Your Warranty: Hacking Glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPethpwuYEk)
you can connect BT keyboard/mouse to your glass.

If you don't have any bluetooth input devices you can try converting your android phone into bluetooth keyboard via `BluePutDroid` app. It requires rooted phone and supports a [limited amount of devices](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=940511), but if it runs, your phone would be detected as BT keyboard.